# Графика в java

Tags: графика, java

Я пишу небольшую стратегию на java. С реализационной частью, вроде, получается, а вот с графической частью не знаю, что делать. С помощью чего можно реализовать графику в java? Кроме java, знаю только Delphi. С графикой в Delphi работал, может быть, пока не поздно начать делать проект на Delphi?

Comment: А какого рода графика? Векторная наверное, раз стратегия. В делфи тоже сильно не раскрутишься мне кажется. Хотя если OpenGL или DirectX использовать то может быть и можно что-то серьезное сделать... Программируйте на том, что хорошо знаете. Если java плохо знаете, то все же тогда делфи. Вообще для игры бы посоветовал бы C++.

Comment: >Вообще для игры бы посоветовал бы C++

почему?

Comment: а как Вам такое http://jmonkeyengine.org/

Comment: с++ это конечно круто, но это не панацея.